# Singleton class and meta class

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaclass

I know what a singleton class is. Singleton classes are used to hold the singleton method defined for an object. Are meta class and singleton class the same? Can anyone explain what meta class is? Some information on meta class gives examples of singleton class. Are both the same thing or somehow related to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think meta class is an unofficial way that some people refer to singleton class as. Besides singleton class, eigenclass is another official name for it.

Answer (score 4):

In the book - *The Ruby Programming Language* in page #257, *Matz* explained what you asked as below :

> The singleton methods of an object are instance methods of the anonymous *eigenclass* associated withthat object. *“Eigen” is a German word meaning (roughly) “self,” “own,” “particularto,” or “characteristic of.”* The *eigenclass* is also called the *singleton class* or (less com-monly) the *metaclass*. *The term “eigenclass” is not uniformly accepted within the Ruby community, but it is the term we’ll use in this book.*

Comment: Only the last two sentences in the citation are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For a long, there was no official name for what is now known as the "singleton class". People called it all sorts of different things, including but not limited to:

- singleton class
- eigenclass
- metaclass
- virtual class
- ghost class
- shadow class

Those all refer to the same thing.

However, some of those already have established meanings. "Metaclass" for example already has a meaning in OO in general and in Smalltalk specifically, and it means something different from how it was once used in Ruby, which lead to confusion, especially given Ruby's close relation to Smalltalk.

Likewise, "virtual class" means something different. (Plus, the term is also used inside the YARV source code for a third concept.)

Comment: I have seen most of them. Virtual class means something different. Where I can read what is the difference between metaclass and virtual class?

Comment: In the YARV C source code, "virtual class" refers to classes which are part of the method lookup chain, but are not considered the class of the object. These are singleton classes and include classes (the proxy classes which are generated when you mix a module into a class). More generally, virtual classes are nested classes which can be overridden in subclasses (analogous to how virtual methods are members of classes which can be overridden in subclasses). Beta (a successor to Simula) and Newspeak (a Smalltalk-descendant) have virtual classes. They were also planned for Scala, but abandoned.

Comment: So, in Ruby, the term "virtual class" was *already* used wrongly, and then started getting used in a different wrong way.

Comment: So, at Ruby level it is just a `module`?

Comment: @DarekNędza: Virtual classes are a special case of nested classes. Ruby has neither. You could emulate virtual classes by having a method that returns a class which can then be overridden in a subclass, though.